# Could an F-35 really be 3% rare-earth?

Tags: aerospace-materials, electronics, f-35, engineering

The Financial Times' [China targets rare earth export curbs to hobble US defence industry](https://www.ft.com/content/d3ed83f4-19bc-4d16-b510-415749c032c1) states:

> Fighter jets such as the F-35, a Lockheed Martin aircraft, rely heavily on rare earths for critical components such as electrical power systems and magnets. A Congressional Research Service report said that **each F-35 required 417kg of rare-earth materials**.

[Rare Earth elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare-earth_element#List) are commonplace rather than rare in high tech devices and systems these days, but usually in small quantities. The exception are rare-earth permanent magnets used in electric motors and generators.

But 417 kg sounds like a lot; it's 3.1% of a [reported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II#Specifications_(F-35A)) 13,290 kg dry weight of an F-35A.

Could this be true? Or are they counting for just for example the whole motor rather than the rare earth within it?

Comment: That seems unlikely, more likely there are 417kg of materials that have some rare earths in them rather than having 417kg of rare earths.

Comment: [Here's the report they seem to be referring to;](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/natsec/R41744.pdf)  see page 4.  (920 lbs ≈ 417 kg.)  The claim seems to stem from a DOD report to congress from September 2012 titled "Report on Feasibility and Desirability of Recycling, Recovery, and Reprocessing Rare Earth Elements" (referred to on p. 6 of [this report](https://www.gao.gov/assets/680/675165.pdf)), but I have been unable to find the report itself.  It wouldn't surprise me if the details are classified.

Comment: I would expect that to include all the rare earth materials in all the supporting equipment on the ground, plus everything that gets lost in the supply chain.

Comment: Agree 417 kg sounds like a lot.  As you say, the only bulk application of rare earths is magnets.  Why would an aircraft have half a ton of magnets?  The Congressional Research Service reports refers to 'rare earth materials' and says 'each F-35 Lightning II aircraft would require approximately 920 pounds of these materials'.  This references some other report which is apparently not public.  'rare earth materials' is pretty vague.  Guess:  the original report is referring to the quantity of rare earth ores required in the supply chain, rather than to end-product metals.

Comment: @uhoh: updated answer

Comment: @ymb1 that's a lot of lanthanum! Okay I guess the answer is "ya, probably..." :-)

Comment: @uhoh: Now interestingly, the F-35 is built from a beryllium-aluminum alloy; beryllium is not REE, but it is -- unlike REE -- actually rare :D I also made this [size comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2vMM.png).

Comment: @ymb1 excellent, what a comparison!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ~416 kg is confirmed by multiple sources. The most useful I found<sup>[1]</sup> uses a comparison:

> | Product | REE |
> | --- | --- |
> | Mobile phone | 0.0005 kg |
> | Air conditioner | 0.12 kg |
> | Toyota Prius | 15 kg |
> | Lockheed-Martin F-35 | 416 kg |
> | Navy surface ships | 1818 kg |
> | Navy submarines | 3636 kg |

Based on @MichaelSeifert's input, I've found confirmation for the REE in a Toyota Prius – its curb weight is 1380 kg ([toyota.ca](https://www.toyota.ca/toyota/en/vehicles/prius/models-specifications)):

> Each electric Prius motor requires 1 kilogram (2.2 lb) of neodymium, and each battery uses 10 to 15 kg (22-33 lb) of lanthanum. **That number will nearly double** under Toyota's plans to boost the car's fuel economy. ([reuters.com](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-mining-toyota-idUSTRE57U02B20090831); emphasis mine)

If a Toyota Prius is **1.1–2.3% rare earth by mass,** then 3% for the F-35 shouldn't be surprising.

Worth [noting](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rare-earth_element&oldid=1005857741):

> Despite their name, rare-earth elements are relatively plentiful in Earth's crust, with cerium being the 25th most abundant element at 68 parts per million, **more abundant than copper.** [emphasis mine]

---

1: Ganguli, Rajive, and Douglas R. Cook. "Rare earths: A review of the landscape." MRS Energy & Sustainability 5 (2018). ([PDF](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1557/mre.2018.7.pdf))

Comment: If those figures are correct, then a Prius (curb weight of 1500 kg) is approximately 1% rare earths by mass.  I could believe that a high-tech military F-35 uses about three times more rare earths, as a proportion of its weight, than a consumer-grade Prius does.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree.  Furthermore, the seldom-seen Stealth Prius consists of over 4% rare earth metals.

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket: Well, if it was easily seen, then it wouldn't be a stealth Prius, now would it?

Comment: @jamesqf TWTJ! :) https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=twtj

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket: But I am not an Urbanite, nor do  I speak or understand Urbanese :-)